# Change value of {{ vari }} on Vue

Tags: vue.js

im just starting on vue js and ive been struggling for hours to do very simple things like change the value of {{vari}} using JS on the mounted function. Can somebody provide me an answer? I want the paragraph to display a different message from teste when it enters the mounted() function

```
<template>
<div class="teste">
    <p>{{vari}}</p>
</div>
```

```
export default {
    name: 'Schedual',
    data: function() {
    return {
        vari: "teste",

    }
},

mounted () {  

//change value of {{vari}}

}
}
```

EDIT: thanks. why doesnt it work when i try to change it inside a function ?

```
 mounted () { 



    atualiza();

    function atualiza(){ 

      this.vari = String("bla");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <div class="teste">
    <p>{{ vari }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

export default {
  name: 'Schedual',

  data: function () {
    return {
      vari: 'teste'
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    this.vari = 'other value'
  }
}
```

This:

```
mounted () {
  function actualiza () { 
    this.vari = 'bla'
  }

  actualiza()
}
```

will not work, because actualiza() function will create own scope, own "this" object. You have two options. First, save "this" object to variable and use saved "this":

```
mounted () {
  let self = this

  function actualiza () { 
    self.vari = 'bla'
  }

  actualiza()
}
```

Second option, more common, is to use arrow function, instead of ordinary function, as these arrow functions doesn't have own "this" object:

```
mounted () {
  const actualiza = () => { 
    this.vari = 'bla'
  }

  actualiza()
}
```

This will work also, but... Try to not create functions in functions. Create all functions as methods of Vue component. It will improve your code readability and you will have no more problems with context:

```
<template>
  <div class="teste">
    <p>{{ vari }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

export default {
  name: 'Schedual',

  data: function () {
    return {
      vari: 'teste'
    }
  },

  methods: {
    actualiza () {
      this.vari = 'bla'
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    this.actualiza()
  }
}
```

Comment: anyone knows why if i change the value inside a function it doesnt work anymore ?